# Collect a range value from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

This is just an example. A workbook contains 10 sheets. They are

Summary/Index/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF/GG/Version

Now, user want to select data particularly D column from AA sheet to FF sheet. This is just an example. In real scenario a worksheet can contain n number of sheets and the code what I am looking is should not collect the values from the sheet1. it should collect the values as per the user wish and stop where user wants.

Hope this example is clear.

Thank you!

Comment: Cannot range between sheets. Get range from each sheet and sum them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Java and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Below link has examples of reading excel file using apache poi in java.

http://www.journaldev.com/2562/java-readwrite-excel-file-using-apache-poi-api